# Getting a segmentation error in c

Tags: c, pointers, free

My problem is that i am not sure how to allocate memory properly. I have researched it but to no avail. Some help regarding malloc would be great.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, a[5000], c = 1, m, n, input;

    scanf("%d", &input);

    for (i = 0; i <= 9999; i += 2) {

        a[c] = i;
        c++;

    }

    for (n = 2; n < 1118; n++) {

        for (m = a[n]; m < a[5000]; m++) {

            a[m] = a[m+1];
        }
    }

    printf("%d", a[input]);

    free (*a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you didn't search very far. Did you look at SO documentation? https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/4726/memory-management#t=201610092024124038819

Answer (score 2):

First of all, C arrays have 0-based indexing. By setting the intial value of `c` to `1` and then using as index inside the loop, you're going off-by-one. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After that, you don't need to do `free (*a);`, `a` is an array, not a pointer returned by a memory allocator functions, `malloc()` or family.

That said, in this code, `*a` does not give you a pointer, at all, it is same as `a[0]` which is of type `int`.

Finally, without any bound checking from user supplied value of `input`, using `a[input]` may very well be accessing out of bound memory, causing UB.

FWIW, passing a pointer to `free()` which is not returned previously by `malloc()` and family also invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

'a' is allocated on stack therefore no need to free it.

You only need to free variables allocated by `*alloc` family of functions.

Answer (score -1):

malloc takes one argument - the number of bytes to allocate. It returns a void pointer (which is a pointer to a section of memory that can hold any data type).

Here's an example.

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

This allocates a 10-element array of integers. Note it leaves your data uninitialized, so the contents of the array are undefined. There's a function called [calloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) that *does* initialize it to zeros.

Also, a style tip. You might try to cast the result of a malloc call to a pointer for the type of data you will store in it (for example, `int *array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);`. This is frowned upon by C programmers for reasons explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) post.